# HTTP parser for Lua

Tags: http, lua

I'm trying to parse http POST requests in Lua. My implementation works, but eats a hell lot of CPU load. This is critical, hence it is on an embedded platform.

I've looked on other implementations, but they can't fit, because my image is hardly fit in the memory, so I wouldn't use another library. I rolled my own parser, but it uses too much of system resource. Question is how could I optimize this to have lower CPU load.

This is an OpenWRT based system, so I only have Lua 5.1. This is the core function that looks for the boundary (in str variable). It reads the input block by block, and seeks for it.

The other solution would be to use LUCI libraries to do the heavy lifting, but I don't want my code to be integrated in LUCI.

```
--look for a pattern (str) and copy input until it is found to the output.
local function writeuntil(in_fp, str, out_fp)

    local buff = ""
    local ret = false
    local bs = 4096 --Block size. The amount of data to read at once

    local c = in_fp:read(bs)
    local strStartPos = 1

    while c do
        local blockLen = string.len(c) --Not sure that a whole block is read, so get the size of the actual block.
        local found = string.find(c, str, 1, true) --Try to locate str, so we don't have much work.
        if (found ~= nil) then
            if found > 2 then
                out_fp:write(string.sub(c, 1, found - 1))
            end
            ret = true
            break --we are done
        else --Try to mach str till the end of the block
            local strPos = string.find(c, string.sub(str, strStartPos, strStartPos), 1, true) --try to locate the first character
            if strPos then --There is a starting character in the block
                if (strPos > 1) then
                        out_fp:write(string.sub(c, 1, strPos - 1))
                end
                for i = strPos, blockLen do --iterate through the block
                    local ch = string.sub(c, i, i)
                    if ch == string.sub(str, strStartPos, strStartPos) then
                        buff = buff .. ch
                        if string.len(buff) == string.len(str) then
                            ret = true
                            break --We're done
                        end
                        strStartPos = strStartPos + 1
                    else --Lost track. Output.
                        if string.len(buff) > 0 then
                            out_fp:write(buff)
                            buff = ""
                        end
                        out_fp:write(ch)
                        strStartPos = 1
                    end
                end
            else
                out_fp:write(c)
            end
        end
        if ret then
            break
        end
        c = in_fp:read(bs) --read next block
    end
    return ret
end
```

Comment: You are starting to search for individual characters too early.  Change your line #21 with the following:  `local strPos = string.find(c, string.sub(str, strStartPos, strStartPos), math.max(1, #c - #str + strStartPos + 1), true) --try to locate the first character`

Comment: I don't see if it would help. Str can be at any position in the buffer.

Comment: This will reduce a lot of useless searches.  Just try it.

Comment: Why not use LuCI? It's already there, so you might as well use it.

Comment: I couldn't make LuCI (or libuci) to implement what I needed. A single CGI script at a specific location just to support the file upload. If you can help me with that, that is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Egor, you were right, but I ended up this solution. It is now uses much less CPU. This not perfect hence scp is faster (although that is implemented in C).

```
--look for a pattern (str) and copy input until it is found to the output.
local function writeuntil(in_fp, str, out_fp)

    local buff = ""
    local ret = false
    local bs = 4096 --Block size. The amount of data to read at once

    local c = in_fp:read(bs)
    local strStartPos = 1
    local lastStrPos = 1
    local needData = true

    while c do
        local blockLen = string.len(c) --Not sure that a whole block is read, so get the size of the actual block.
        local found = string.find(c, str, 1, true) --Try to locate str, so we don't have much work.
        if (found ~= nil) then
            if found > 1 then
                if #buff > 0 then
                    out_fp:write(buff)
                end
                out_fp:write(string.sub(c, 1, found - 1))
            end
            ret = true
            break --we are done
        else --Try to mach str till the end of the block
            local strPos = string.find(c, string.sub(str, strStartPos, strStartPos), lastStrPos, true) --try to locate the first character
            if strPos then --There is a starting character in the block
                out_fp:write(string.sub(c, lastStrPos, strPos - 1))
                for i = strPos, blockLen do --iterate through the block
                    local ch = string.sub(c, i, i)
                    if ch == string.sub(str, strStartPos, strStartPos) then
                        buff = buff .. ch
                        if string.len(buff) == string.len(str) then
                            ret = true
                            break --We're done
                        end
                        strStartPos = strStartPos + 1
                        lastStrPos = i + 1
                    else --Lost track. Output.
                        if string.len(buff) > 0 then
                            out_fp:write(buff)
                            buff = ""
                        end
                        out_fp:write(ch)
                        strStartPos = 1
                        if i == blockLen then
                            needData = true
                        else
                            lastStrPos = i + 1
                            needData = false
                        end
                        break
                    end
                end
            else
                if ret == false then
                    if string.len(buff) > 0 then
                        out_fp:write(buff)
                        buff = ""
                    end
                    out_fp:write(string.sub(c, lastStrPos))
                    lastStrPos = 1
                    needData = true
                else
                    break
                end
            end
        end
        if ret then
            break
        end
        if needData then
            c = in_fp:read(bs) --read next block
            lastStrPos = 1
        end
    end
    return ret
end
```